# Creating a shared library linked against a static library using CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

This is on Ubuntu. Using CMake 3.16

I'm using CMake along with `ExternalProject_Add()` to build a shared library.
The shared library will linked with a static library, which is built as a external project.

You can see an example of it here: https://github.com/bdurrani/poppler-wrapper/blob/d81ddd98f77ce0969a86e34bd1256f8f4e0c7b50/poppler-wrapper-lib/wrapperLib/CMakeLists.txt#L24

```
set(POPPLER_CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install")

include(ExternalProject)

SET(POPPLER_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install/include/poppler/cpp")
SET(POPPLER_CPP_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install/lib)

if(UNIX)
  SET(BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${POPPLER_CPP_LIB_DIR}/libpoppler-cpp.a)
endif()

# set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

ExternalProject_Add(PopplerDownload
  URL https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.10.0.tar.xz
  BUILD_ALWAYS OFF
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${BUILD_BYPRODUCTS}
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -D BUILD_GTK_TESTS=OFF
    -D BUILD_QT5_TESTS=OFF
    -D ENABLE_QT5=OFF
    -D ENABLE_QT6=OFF
    -D ENABLE_GLIB=OFF
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
    -D ENABLE_GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION=OFF
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${POPPLER_CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)

message("Poppler includes ${POPPLER_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}}")
message("Poppler libs ${BUILD_BYPRODUCTS}}")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${POPPLER_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(Poppler::Cpp SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Poppler::Cpp 
PROPERTIES 
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${BUILD_BYPRODUCTS}
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${POPPLER_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}"
  POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
  )
```

The poppler external project builds just fine.
I verified that the `includes` folder has headers present.
And `libs` folder contains a couple of `.a` files present (`libpoppler-cpp.a` and `libpoppler.a`).
So I know the install step worked fine.

However linked with my shared lib fails

```sh
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/bdurrani/github/poppler-wrapper/poppler-wrapper-lib/build --config RelWithDebInfo --target all -j 14 --
[build] [2/4  25% :: 0.623] Building CXX object wrapperLib/CMakeFiles/wrapper.dir/page.cpp.o
[build] [2/4  50% :: 0.708] Building CXX object wrapperLib/CMakeFiles/wrapper.dir/document.cpp.o
[build] [3/4  75% :: 0.830] Linking CXX shared library wrapperLib/libwrapper.so
[build] FAILED: wrapperLib/libwrapper.so 
[build] : && /bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9 -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   -shared -Wl,-soname,libwrapper.so -o wrapperLib/libwrapper.so wrapperLib/CMakeFiles/wrapper.dir/document.cpp.o wrapperLib/CMakeFiles/wrapper.dir/page.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/bdurrani/github/poppler-wrapper/poppler-wrapper-lib/build/wrapperLib/install/lib:  wrapperLib/install/lib/libpoppler-cpp.a && :
[build] /usr/bin/ld: wrapperLib/install/lib/libpoppler-cpp.a(poppler-private.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZSt4cerr@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
[build] /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can see that my wrapper is already being built using `-fPIC` in the line above.
So I enabled `-D CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON` for the external project build.

It looks like this now

```
ExternalProject_Add(PopplerDownload
  URL https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.10.0.tar.xz
  BUILD_ALWAYS OFF
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${BUILD_BYPRODUCTS}
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -D BUILD_GTK_TESTS=OFF
    -D BUILD_QT5_TESTS=OFF
    -D ENABLE_QT5=OFF
    -D ENABLE_QT6=OFF
    -D ENABLE_GLIB=OFF
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
    -D ENABLE_GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION=OFF
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
    -D CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${POPPLER_CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

Now I get a couple of missing symbol errors. Probably because all those symbols are in `libPoppler.a` and I need to somehow add it to the target.

So I did the following

```
set_target_properties(Poppler::Cpp 
PROPERTIES 
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${BUILD_BYPRODUCTS}
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES "poppler;poppler-cpp"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${POPPLER_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}"
  POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
  )
```

I'm still seeing link errors though.
Fewer than before.

How does one correctly set up multiple static libraries as part of a target? I only have two static libs generated so I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: "Now I get a couple of missing symbol errors. Probably because all those symbols are in libPoppler.a" - It is hard to tell the reason of the errors without viewing them and your code.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I need to try and simplify this further. Specifically, is the way I'm linking the multiple static libs correct?